# Create new user in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, webhooks

I've web-hook configured at Yext.com. And it triggers when Location is created/modified. And I am posting those data to my WordPress plugin file `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-file.php`. And I am storing request data in this way:

```
 $webhook_posted_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $location_info = json_decode($webhook_posted_json, true);
```

I am getting data when I update/create location information on yext.com in json format and then I decode it.

Now I've the data stored in variables as below:

```
$location_name = $location_info[location][locationName]; // Get Location Name
$location_email = $location_info[location][emails][0]; // Get primary contact email
```

Here comes the main part for creation of new user: My Problem is user is not getting registered with below code. Do you know why it is not triggering ?

```
$the_user_id = 0;
// Check if user exist or not!
if ( !function_exists( 'get_user_by' ) ) { 
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php'; 
} 
if ( username_exists( $location_name ) ){
    $the_user = get_user_by('login', $location_name);
    $the_user_id = $the_user->ID;
}
else{
   $the_user_id = 0;
}


if ( !function_exists( 'wp_insert_user' ) ) { 
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php'; 
} 
$password = wp_generate_password();
// An array, object, or WP_User object of user data arguments. 
$userdata = array( 
    'ID' => $the_user_id, 
    'user_pass' => $password, 
    'user_login' => $location_name, 
    'user_email' => $location_email, 
    'role' => 'editor' 
); 

// NOTICE! Understand what this does before running. 
$result = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

I am having a Fatal error when I visit the `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-file.php` stating : `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'ABSPATHWPINC/pluggable.php'`.

Can anyone help me out here on how to handle webhook and create new user based on the data ?

Comment: Please provide the structure of your `Users` table, the content of your POST data, and a summary of the desired change. Make your edits to the question by clicking "edit"

Comment: Take a look at my codebase What I am trying to do!

Comment: Hi VJ, welcome to stackoverflow. People put this post on hold probably because your current title "Create new user in WordPress" is too broad but when going into the description, it is to specific on a business process/methodology. Perhaps match your title with the specific goal. Perhaps picking a more specific title is a suggestion.